# Can you find out what the cumulative distribution function is if you know the random variable X?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have a theoretic question on my probability class. Suppose that you know the X random variable. Can you calculate the cumulative distribution function? If not, why not?

Comment: Each probability distribution has its own CDF, and this relationship is one-to-one. If you claim that you know the distribution of a certain random variable, then you know its CDF. There are several functions which characterize the distribution, e.g. pdf/pmf, mgf (if exist), and characteristic function. Given any one of these functions will allow you to compute the CDF.

Comment: Define "know the $X$ random variable".  What does this entail?  Do we know the PDF of $X$?

Comment: The most direct connection between a random variable $X$ and its cdf is $F_X(x)=P(X<x)$

Answer (score 0):

If you know the distribution of X, the cumulative is the integral of its density function. So yes, I can.

If you have drawins from X, you may be able to fit a distribution, so that you get an estimated continuous density function. You may not be able to express the integral in terms of elementary functions (e.g. the cumulative of a normal distribution), but you may have a numerical approximation. So yes, I can.